# Why is movement of water through cell walls considered the apoplast and symplast pathway?

Tags: botany, life, osmosis, movement, pathway

Why would the movement of water through cell walls be considered the apoplast and symplast pathway? I understand why it's considered the apoplast pathway (as the water is moving through a non-living part by diffusion) but should it not be considered symplast since that is only for when water moves through living structures? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your question could be a bit more clear, but I think you are referring to this-
[image: Fig. 1]

> The apoplast is the space outside the plasma membrane consisting of intercellular spaces where the material diffuses freely; it includes parts such as the cell wall and intercellular spaces.

> The symplast consists of the cytoplasmic network of plant cells interconnected by plasmodesmata.

I suppose, in the motion of the upper stream of water (as indicated by the blue arrow in the diagram) you can see that to *enter* the symplastic pathway, the water has to *first* pass through the apoplastic pathway, in a sense. That is, it cannot 'teleport' directly into the cell's protoplasm, it has to pass through the cell wall.

Hope that clears things up.